# (C#) parse imdb 'soundtracks.list' to csv

Tags: c#, csv, imdb

I just downloaded the soundtracks.list file from http://www.imdb.com/interfaces and I need help converting it into a csv file using C#. I read about imdbpy but I don't know anything about python.

The structure of soundtracks.list is like this:

```
# #1 Cheerleader Camp (2010) (V)
- "Drop Dat Booty"
  Performed by Ken Cain and Ben Forman
  Written and Produced by Ken Cain and Ben Forman
- "Endless View"
  Written and Produced by Sterling
  Performed by Darlings of the Day

# #2 Chick (2014)
- "Number 1 Chick and Number 2 chick by D Player"

# Star Wars (1977)
- "Star Wars (Main Theme)" (uncredited)
  Written by John Williams
  Performed by London Symphony Orchestra
- "The Hologram/Binary Sunset" (uncredited)
  Written by John Williams
  Performed by London Symphony Orchestra
```

I need to convert it into this format:

```
movie,song,info
"#1 Cheerleader Camp (2010) (V)","Drop Dat Booty","Performed by Ken Cain and Ben Forman Written and Produced by Ken Cain and Ben Forman"
"#1 Cheerleader Camp (2010) (V)","Endless View","Written and Produced by Sterling Performed by Darlings of the Day"
"#2 Chick (2014)","Number 1 Chick and Number 2 chick by D Player",""
"Star Wars (1977)","Star Wars (Main Theme) (uncredited)","Written by John Williams Performed by London Symphony Orchestra"
"Star Wars (1977)","The Hologram/Binary Sunset (uncredited)","Written by John Williams Performed by London Symphony Orchestra"
```

Comment: What's your specific problem? " I need help" generally doesn't make a good question

Comment: I need help on how it can be done.

Comment: Have you tried doing something?

Comment: Seems like you're asking someone to do it for you, not help on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started. But in the future, first try to get to the solution, then ask specific questions. There will be lots of people trying to help you here ;)

Best of luck with C#!

```
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program3
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter("output.csv"))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader("input.txt"))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("movie,song,info");

                string movie = "";
                string song = "";
                string info = "";

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();

                    // movie
                    if (line.StartsWith("# "))
                    {
                        // forget previous song & info
                        song = "";
                        info = "";
                        // remember movie
                        movie = line.Substring(2);
                    }
                    // song
                    else if (line.StartsWith("- "))
                    {
                        // write song info to csv
                        if (song != "")
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("\"" + movie + "\", \"" + song + "\", \"" + info + "\"");
                        }
                        // forget previous song info
                        info = "";
                        // remember song
                        song = line.Substring(2);
                    }
                    // song info
                    else if (line.StartsWith("  "))
                    {
                        // remember info
                        if (info != "")
                        {
                            info += "";
                        }
                        info += line;
                    }
                    // end of movie
                    else if (line == "")
                    {
                        // write song info to csv
                        if (song != "")
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("\"" + movie + "\", \"" + song + "\", \"" + info + "\"");
                        }
                        // forget movie, song & info
                        movie = "";
                        song = "";
                        info = "";
                    }
                }

                // write song info to csv
                if (song != "")
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("\"" + movie + "\", \"" + song + "\", \"" + info + "\"");
                }

                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```